# getting past a scrapy login

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and having trouble getting past a login page:

```
allowed_domains = ['brp.secure.force.com']
start_urls = ['https://brp.secure.force.com/Login']

formdata = {'j_id0:j_id5:Login1_Dealer_No' : 'XXXXXX', 'j_id0:j_id5:Login1_UserName' : 'XXXXXX', 'j_id0:j_id5:Login1_Password' : 'XXXXXX'},
```

Login appears to fail as my response is the login page.
I'm thinking I must have incorrect parameter names. How does one work on this type of issue?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: Please edit your code in your question so it is a [mre] and actually includes the code you’re having a problem with which is where you login to the page.

Comment: thank you. i'm not even close here. will post another question

Answer (score 0):

this is a javascript ajax page. needs much more kung foo